# How to deserialize a List(Of Object) from JSON?

Tags: json, vb.net

I have a `List(Of Object)` that I am using in a property of type `IEnumerable(Of Object)`. I can serialize it fine but cannot work out then how to deserialize it from JSON back to a `List(Of Object)`. Any help would be really great please.

My ViewModel:

```
Public Class ViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase

    Public Class MapSettings
        <Display(Name:="Map Name", Description:="Enter a optional name for the map.", GroupName:="Map Settings")>
        Public Property MapName As String
        <Display(Name:="Map Description", Description:="Enter a optional description for the map.", GroupName:="Map Settings")>
        Public Property MapDescription As String

        <Display(Name:="Map Comments", Description:="Enter optional comments for the map.", GroupName:="Map Settings")>
        Public Property MapComments As String

        <Display(Name:="Map Version", Description:="Enter a optional version for the map.", GroupName:="Map Settings")>
        Public Property MapVersion As String
    End Class

    Public Class GeneralSettings
        <Display(Name:="Route Colour", Description:="Sets the colour of the routes design line on the map.", GroupName:="General Settings")>
        Public Property Foreground As Color

    End Class

    Private _myItems() As IEnumerable(Of Object)
    Public Property MyItems() As IEnumerable(Of Object)
        Get
            If _myItems Is Nothing Then
                Return New List(Of Object)() From {
                          New MapSettings,
                          New GeneralSettings With {.Foreground = Colors.Blue}
                      }
            Else
                Return _myItems
            End If

        End Get
        Set(value As IEnumerable(Of Object))
            _myItems = value
            OnPropertyChanged()
        End Set

    End Property
End Class
```

My serialize code that I cannot complete:

```
Dim MyItems_New = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MyItems???)(MyJsonString)
```

JSON:

```
{
  "MyItems": [
    {
      "MapName": null,
      "MapDescription": null,
      "MapComments": null,
      "MapVersion": null
    },
    {
      "Foreground": "#FF0000FF"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I already tried that but get the error: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object][]'.'

Comment: The JSON that you are trying to deserialize, is it only an array of items or does it contain all the properties of your entire class? It would be great if you could give us a sample of what `MyJsonString` contains.

Comment: {"MyItems":[{"MapName":null,"MapDescription":null,"MapComments":null,"MapVersion":null},{"Foreground":"#FF0000FF"}]}

Comment: This is my code to serialize: Dim myItems = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myVM.MyItems)

Comment: Hmmm. Unfortunately, since JSON is typeless, the deserializer doesn't know what types it should deserialize the items to. That's why you get a `JObject` instead, and the `MyItems` property of that object will be a `JArray`. One solution would be to add a `Type` property to all your classes, which would let you check which type you would convert a `JObject` to. Another would be to check which properties exist and based on that decide which type it is. If either isn't an option because you don't know all types which might be added to the list, then I don't think there's much you can do.

Comment: OK, thanks for the pointers Vincent

Comment: With `Return New List(Of Object)() From { ... }` you're creating an anonymous object that is the combination of those two classes, creating two objects where one is missing the properties of the other (so, you actually have a single object with missing properties). You could use an intermediate model (e.g., `public class MyItemModel public Property ItemMap as MapSettings public property Settings as GeneralSettings`) and add a RootObject as `public class MyItems public Property Items as IList(Of MyItemModel)`. So you will be using two distinct named objects.

Comment: @Jimi Not quite correct. `From` is a [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/) which internally calls the collection's `Add` method. Using it is the equivalent to initializing the list and then calling `Add` multiple times. There are no anonymous objects involved in this case.

Comment: @Visual Vincent  We're talking about two different things. The class initializer functionality is not in discussion. It's the resulting JSON I'm talking about. With the current `List<object>` initializer, you'll generate the JSON shown in the question. Those two objects (`{ "MapName": null, ...}, { "Foreground": "#FF0000FF" }`) are one single object type with missing properties. I'm proposing to use two different object types, creating an intermediate object that exposes two properties of type `MapSettings` and `GeneralSettings`, to generate a JSON with two different objects...

Comment: @Visual Vincent ... Otherwise, you might as well merge `MapSettings` and `GeneralSettings` in as single object, since you get the same result anyway. Of course, the `List<object>` is not adeguate. The OP could use a `RootObject` with an `IList<TheIntermediateType>` property type and serialize/deserialize this RootObject.

Comment: I have merged the MapSettings and GeneralSettings but still cannot get the IList to work correctly, can someone please post a code snippet to help?

Comment: @Jimi I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Why do you say they're the same object but with "missing properties"? JSON can contain multiple objects with different properties (which I don't doubt you know as well). However, I do understand and agree that using a single type is preferred in a list and in a strongly typed language like VB.NET, but it appears that this is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Visual Vincent  You can have a better view of it if you serialize it and then deserialize that `List<object>`. The deserialization will use the same object as model. I'm proposing the opposite of packing all properties in a single object. I'm proposing to create to 2 distinct types using an intermediate object. Since I don't have Visual Studio, I wrote an example of what I mean [in a PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/pJ0Qf9Lu).

Comment: @Jimi Ah, I see. Thanks for explaining. I haven't had access to VS all day either, so that's why I haven't seen the result yet.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that Newtonsoft has built-in support for type handling, which can be enabled by setting the [`JsonSerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling` property](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) and passing it to the serialization methods. As long as you control the input, this should let you both serialize and deserialize your list without a problem.

Serialize:

```
Dim myItems = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myVM.MyItems, Formatting.None, New JsonSerializerSettings() With { .TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto })
```

Deserialize:

```
Dim myItems_New = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Object))(MyJsonString, New JsonSerializerSettings() With { .TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto })
```

In your question, `MyJsonString` appears to be a serialized version of your `ViewModel` class rather than just the list itself. If this is the case, change `DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Object))` to `DeserializeObject(Of ViewModel)`.

Resulting JSON:

```
[
  {
    "$type": "MapSettings, YourProjectNamespace",
    "MapName": "New York",
    "MapDescription": "Map over New York",
    "MapComments": null,
    "MapVersion": "v1"
  },
  {
    "$type": "GeneralSettings, YourProjectNamespace",
    "Foreground": "#FF0000"
  }
]
```

**Try it online (C#):**
https://dotnetfiddle.net/0jCIGL

However, if these two classes are all you are planning to use this list for, then you'd be better off using something along the lines of [Jimi's proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234266/how-to-deserialize-a-listof-object-from-json#comment104685240_59234266), as then you're always working with strongly-typed objects.